# formatear números en AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Buenas tengo un proyecto AngularJS el cual tengo una variable por ejemplo

```
<p>{{item.financialPrice | number}}</p>
```

la variable en base de datos esta como: 17000 pero el código con el formateo me devuelve el siguiente formato 17,000 
Al al ser un proyecto de España debería devolverme 17.000 el "." en vez de la "," en los miles ya que la , es para el decimal.
He investigado y he visto que puede deberse a la configuración regional de angular.
Pero no se como podría cambiarla para que me formatee el numero correctamente.
Si hay alguna otra solución también me serviría.
Gracias

Comment: Pensando en que `number` es un filtro, una buena posibilidad es crear un filtro personalizado que devuelva el formato que pides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a poner en práctica lo que estaba señalando en los comentarios.

[De acuerdo a la documentación de AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number) (en inglés), se especifica que el filtro `number`, que estás usando:

> Formats a number as text. (Formatea un número como texto.)

Con ello en mente, una solución factible es crear un **filtro personalizado** que haga lo mismo, formatear un número a texto, pero bajo los términos que nosotros queramos establecer.

Como lo que se quiere es un número en el que los puntos marquen los miles, hay que definir ello en el filtro.

```
app.filter('miFiltro', function(){
    return function(x){
        let str = '';

        /* Código que transforma tu número a string */

        return str;
    };
});
```

Supongamos que tu base de datos devuelve solamente los números sin decimales (`17000`) como bien lo especificaste, ese va a ser el caso base. Eso va a permitir definir el algoritmo, y subsecuentemente el código dentro de tu filtro.

En el código de abajo vas a ver la implementación de ese algoritmo dentro de tu filtro:

```
app.filter('numberWithDots', function(){
  return function(x){
    /* Si el número es null o undefined, se devuelven de inmediato */

    if (x == null) {
      return null;
    }

    if (x == undefined) {
      return undefined;
    }

    /* El string del número se construye de derecha a izquierda */

    let str = '';
    let rest, floor;


    do {
      /* En cada iteración, se obtiene el piso de la división del
         número por 1000. */
      rest = x % 1000;
      floor = Math.floor(x / 1000);

      /* Si el piso no es igual a cero,
         se añaden a la izquierda del string el punto
         y los últimos 3 dígitos del número. De lo contrario, se añade
         el resto, también a la izquierda del string */
      str = (floor == 0) ? rest + str : '.' + x.toString().slice(-3) + str; 

      /* Finalmente, se obtiene el piso de la división por 1000
         del número, para la próxima iteración*/
      x = Math.floor(x / 1000);

      /* El ciclo continúa mientras el número sea mayor a 0 */
    } while (x > 0);

    /* Y finalmente se devuelve la representación del número en string */
    return str;
  }
});
```

Aquí lo ves en acción:

```js
const app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.filter('numberWithDots', function() {
  return function(x) {
    if (x == null) {
      return null;
    }

    if (x == undefined) {
      return undefined;
    }

    let str = '';
    let rest, floor;

    do {
      rest = x % 1000;
      floor = Math.floor(x / 1000);

      str = (floor == 0) ? rest + str : '.' + x.toString().slice(-3) + str;

      x = Math.floor(x / 1000);
    } while (x > 0);

    return str;
  }
});

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.myNumber = 17000;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <p>{{myNumber | numberWithDots}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Antes de terminar, un recordatorio: El código dentro del filtro contempla el caso base de que tu base de datos devuelve el número sin decimales. Si se diera el caso de que tu base de datos te devuelve un número de punto flotante, el código dentro del filtro tiene que ser distinto.